# Display the 2nd category name of a custom post type without error if its null?

Tags: posts, customization

I have list items.
These are custom posts.

- Post A belongs to category green and blue
- Post B belongs to category blue
- Post C belongs to category green and blue
- Post D belongs to category green and red
- Post E belongs to category green and blue
- Post F belongs to category blue
- Post G belongs to category blue and yellow

I want to loop each post and display second category name only of the post if there is one. If theres is not display the first category name as default.

So 
A should display category blue

B should be blue

C should be blue

D should be red

E should be blue

F should be blue

G should be yellow

Please help me achieve this using php. 
I beleive get_post _terms() is what needed here but I struggle to do it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of your loop you can get the terms via `wp_get_post_terms` function. Then, check if two or more terms exist. If they do, then use the function `array_slice` to extract the second term that appears in the array:

```
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'YOUR_TAXONOMY', array('orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'fields' => 'all') );

$display_term = (count($term_list) > 1) ? array_slice($array, 1, 1) : $term_list;
```

However, this does not determine how the terms will output from the database. You may want to define the `orderby` parameter to be something specific so you can predict which term will appear second.

Sources:

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php